# How to extract a value from an Org mode table and use it in a Lisp sexp?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm working with `org-mode` tables in Emacs 27.1 on Kali Linux, running Org version 9.3.

I ran across [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7375/can-i-format-cells-in-an-org-mode-table-differently-depending-on-a-formula). Because I'm fairly new, I thought I'd start simple. I have an `org-mode` table that I wanted to have calculate BP readings.  I'm a bit familiar with Lisp so I tried a simple `if` statement in the scratch pad of Emacs:

[image]

It worked just fine, when I ran the `if` statement with `(> 3 2)` it  showed `Greater`, and when I ran it with `(> 2 3)` it showed `Less`, just as it should.

However, in an `org-mode` table it doesn't behave the same:

[image]

That code should display the message `normal` not `abnormal`.

I've verified the reference I'm using using `C-c ?`. Since the number in that column is less than 120 it should show `normal`.

What am I doing wrong here?
This should print `normal` if the number is below 120 and it should print `abnormal` if the number is at least 120.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to do with the conditional. If you want to have the notes column filled in with abnormal or normal, you would have `#+TBLFM: $6='(if (> $3 120) "abnormal" "normal");N`.

You cannot put a src block directly into a TBLFM line, by the way.

Comment: As @éric points out, you cannot put a src block into a TBLFM line: you can put Calc formulas: `$6 = if ($3 > 120, abnormal, normal)` or lisp formulas as in the above comment. See the two sections "Formula syntax for Calc" and "Formula syntax for Lisp" in the section of the manual entitled "The Spreadsheet" , which you can get to with `C-h i g(org)spreadsheet`.

Comment: Thanks eric and NickD.  I misread the information on the link and thought the poster there was mixing elisp and table formulas.  Looks like the formula is only on one line each (two TBLFM lines)  and the rest is elisp.       My intention is to use the table as a way to measure the BP readings so it would involve reading two number and giving an indication based on those two.  I wanted it to run in elsip similiar to how the page I link had a complex formula run.  You both gave me a push in the right direction so likely I can figure the rest. Thank you!

Comment: You seem to treat the table as a datasource in the manner of ‘data science’, where the output of your computations is separate from the source. However, spreadsheets don't generally work that way: instead, you put the results into cells in the table itself. That's how formulas work, and you normally use a non-lisp ‘Calc’ syntax for them. You can also grab cells or ranges from another table with [remote references](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#Remote-references).

Comment: But, since Org is made in Elisp, there seems to be a function for remote references: `org-table-get-remote-range` (see its docs in Emacs). Presumably you can use it to extract values from a table in Elisp code. Note that rectangular ranges are extracted as flat lists, so you might want to convert that back into a list of lists with e.g. [`-partition-all` from dash](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-partition-all-n-list). Also empty cells could be skipped, messing up the structure—[see the flag `E` for formulas](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html#Formula-syntax-for-Calc).

Comment: Ah, [apparently there's a specific feature to use tables in code blocks](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20129/how-can-i-filter-table-in-org-mode#20137), with which I wasn't familiar and which you attempted to use—looks like exactly what you wanted, in fact. But it must be specified on the separate code block, not on the table itself. Also, since the code isn't in table formulas, references like `@4$3` won't work—you'll need to use Elisp functions to get to cell values.